# How to deal with non-numeric missing values with python

Tags: python, data-imputation, missing-data

I have a csv data file which contains a non-numeric column (`tarif`) which can have `hce`, `hp`, ....

The problem is some missing values. As the values are non-numeric (`hce` or `hp`), it is impossible to impute with `mean()`.

Can you suggest ideas to resolve this problem to fill empty columns?

Comment: How to approach this in any specific software is off-topic here: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for guidance on software-related topics. Otherwise there is a statistical question here. A possibility is to use some kind of logit or multiple logit model for imputation. It's not clear from your post whether there are only two possible values or several. (Empty columns are insurmountable; I guess you mean empty cells, or whatever Python calls them.)

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for you quick reply. I have three possible values : either "HC", "HP" or "PTE". Yes I mean empty cell :)

Comment: Imputation with multiple logit then. If that's too complicated, then ignoring rows (or whatever Python calls them) with missings is indicated.

Comment: Ok, Have a you any tutorial ti suggest to me concerning Imputation with multiple logit ? thanks

Comment: I'd Google or find a textbook on multiple imputation. I don't ever do it; I just know about it. If you've never heard of it, it won't be an easy job.

Comment: Just for reference, [this tag search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-data+data-imputation+categorical-data) turns up a couple of hits on CV.